# Docker MariaDB lost data

Tags: mysql, mariadb, docker

I was using the official mariadb 10.3 image as a database with innodb and file per table turned on. A few months ago I pulled the image for a minor release and let it run. This as I now found out did not automatically upgrade the database its self as the logs have been saying to run the mysql_upgrade. The database has not been restarted since that pull.

New data has been added and used in that time however the container restarted and it seems now all data since the pull a few months ago has been lost on certain tables and the .idb files even on backups are saying  there was no modification on the file.

Any suggestions on where this data might have been written too or how to recover it?

error logs pre restart

```
InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_index_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade
```

error logs during crash

```
    Using Linux native AIO
    [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 512M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
[Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=471249973567
[Note] InnoDB: 16 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 16 row operations to undo
[Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 602890104
 InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 170 pages from redo log.
```

All recovery modes were tried but only 6 worked.

```
InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table `database name`.`table name` in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 1216
```

Comment: Is the data kept inside the container, or did you mount it somewhere outside of the container?

Comment: Yes /var/lib/mysql is mounted on to the host machine. The problem is due to the mysql upgrade that wasnt ran, the idb datafiles have somehow not been updated  since the image update even though the new data has been used since that point. seems to make no sense.

Comment: Without looking at command that was used to create the container after the 'upgrade', my guess would be that the data was copied into the container instead of mapped to the host. That would explain why you were able to use it without any issues then. However, the moment the container was removed, the data it contained as removed as well.

Comment: Is this standard mysql functionality?  the old container is just stopped so the diff still exist in /var/lib/docker and there is isnt a file that contain any data.